# How many objects are in the array with the same key

Tags: javascript

I want to count how many objects in my array have the same *name* property, based on a parameter. How can I achieve this?

Actually this is my array:

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"aaa",
      "id":"2100",
      "designation":"developer"
   },
   {  
      "name":"bbb",
      "id":"8888",
      "designation":"team lead"
   },
   {  
      "name":"ccc",
      "id":"6745",
      "designation":"manager"
   },
   {  
      "name":"aaa",
      "id":"9899",
      "designation":"sw"
   }
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"(if it is repeated means,i want to get the length of ii as 2"* What is `ii`?

Comment: i see 4 objects inside of the array.

Comment: This question is not clear at all.  Please clarify what you are asking and what result you expect.

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no length property for Object. Still you can use [**Object.keys**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) which returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties. Then you can use the length property.

```
var a = { "name":"bbb", "id":"8888", "designation":"team lead" }
var m = Object.keys(a).length;
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/nsmay4sr/)

> if it is repeated means,i want to get the length of ii as 2

do you mean to say object with duplicate key?

Comment: I think the question is: How do I find out how many objects there are in the array with the same property value? (Yes, it's not clear.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes,that was my question can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the elements of the array and inspect every property and use a hash table for counting.

```js
var data = [{ "name": "aaa", "id": "2100", "designation": "developer" }, { "name": "bbb", "id": "8888", "designation": "team lead" }, { "name": "ccc", "id": "6745", "designation": "manager" }, { "name": "aaa", "id": "9899", "designation": "sw" }],
    max = 0;

data.forEach(function (a) {
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
        var key = k + '|' + a[k];
        this[key] = (this[key] || 0) + 1;
        if (this[key] > max) {
            max = this[key];
        }
    }, this);
}, {});

console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

To count how many objects has the same *keys*, you can do it:

```js
var array = [  
   {  
      "name":"aaa",
      "id":"2100",
      "designation":"developer"
   },
   {  
      "name":"bbb",
      "id":"8888",
      "designation":"team lead"
   },
   {  
      "name":"ccc",
      "id":"6745",
      "designation":"manager"
   },
   {  
      "name":"aaa",
      "id":"9899",
      "designation":"sw"
   }
];

function countDuplicates(array) {
  var count = {};
  array.forEach(function(element) {
    count[element.name] = (count[element.name] || 0) + 1;
  });
  return count;
}

console.log(countDuplicates(array));
```

**Note:** It's a general way, to count all items not only by a unique key.

However, if you want only to get how many objects with the *key* "aaa", for example, you can just pass a **2nd.** parameter to your function, as below:

```js
var array = [  
   {  
      "name":"aaa",
      "id":"2100",
      "designation":"developer"
   },
   {  
      "name":"bbb",
      "id":"8888",
      "designation":"team lead"
   },
   {  
      "name":"ccc",
      "id":"6745",
      "designation":"manager"
   },
   {  
      "name":"aaa",
      "id":"9899",
      "designation":"sw"
   }
];

function countDuplicates(array, key) {
  var count = {};
  array.forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.name == key) { 
      count[element.name] = (count[element.name] || 0) + 1;
    }
  });
  return count;
}

console.log(countDuplicates(array, "aaa"));
```

Also you can return the objects/counter using the native method [**Array.prototype.filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var array = [  
   {  
      "name":"aaa",
      "id":"2100",
      "designation":"developer"
   },
   {  
      "name":"bbb",
      "id":"8888",
      "designation":"team lead"
   },
   {  
      "name":"ccc",
      "id":"6745",
      "designation":"manager"
   },
   {  
      "name":"aaa",
      "id":"9899",
      "designation":"sw"
   }
];

function countDuplicates(array, key) {
  var filterArray = array.filter(function(element) {
    return element.name == key;
  })
  return filterArray.length;
}

console.log(countDuplicates(array, "aaa"));
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks i got it.In the same scenario if want to check with two properties (name and id) how it will be.

Comment: You can just includes a 2nd. parameter to your function this way: `function countDuplicates(array, key, id) {`, then inside your function add `&&` condition -> `if (element.name == key && element.id == id)`.

Comment: It isn't your question... you even mentioned AngularJs on this.

Comment: @pinkyyy, you're welcome, by the way can you check my answer? (Just click in the left of my answer).

Comment: I need your help i am not getting with two properties.

Answer (score 0):

So you have your data

```
var myData =[
    {
        "name":"aaa",
        "id":"2100",
        "designation":"developer"
    },
    {
        "name":"bbb",
        "id":"8888",
        "designation":"team lead"
    },
    {
        "name":"ccc",
        "id":"6745",
        "designation":"manager"
    },
    {
        "name":"aaa",
        "id":"9899",
        "designation":"sw"
    }
];
```

Lets now make a usefull basic function

```
// A function to get all items with a spesific value on a spesific attribute
var getByAttribute = function(attribute, value, data){
    // Results is an array
    var results = [];

    // For each item
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){

        // Check if attribute match
        if(data[i][attribute] == value)

            // If it match, insert in on results
            results.push(data[i]);
    }

    return results;
};
```

Now we will use the above function to create some more

```
// A function to get all items based on a name
var getByName = function(name, data){
    return getByAttribute("name", name, data);
};

// A function to get all items based on an id
var getById = function(id, data){
    return getByAttribute("id", id, data);
};

// A function to get all items based on a designation
var getByDesignation = function(designation, data){
    return getByAttribute("designation", designation, data);
};
```

So now we can count for example the items with the name "aaa"
using the code

```
var count = getByName("aaa", myData).length;
/*
    getByName("aaa", myData) retrurns 

    [
        {
            "name":"aaa",
            "id":"2100",
            "designation":"developer"
        },
        {
            "name":"aaa",
            "id":"9899",
            "designation":"sw"
        }
    ]

    so if we use on it .length
    we get 2
*/
```